# How to update state from Backend NextJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm using useState in the frontend.

And what I want to do is to update this state from the backend.
The thing is, in the backend I have a Loop, and I don't know how to trigger the setState for each loop, since I can't pass the setState as a parameter, and I saw that the hooks only works on the frontend(browser).

Structure in the frontend

```
const [imageLinks, setImageLinks] useState([])


useEffect ( () => {}, [imageLinks])

return (
  {
    imageLinks.map((link) {
     <img src={link} />
    }
  }
)
```

Structure in the Api endpoint

```
function myFunction (cids, y, z) {
  for (let i = 0; i < cids. length; i+) {
    if (cids[i]) {
      nftTower [i] = await tokenMinterFon(cids[i])
      let imageLink = await axios.get('https://infura-ipfs.io' + 
       cids[i])

// Correct format of the link

...Some logic here 

     let imageLinksFiltered = imageLinks.filter (imageLink =>
     imageLink !== correctFormatLink
      )
      imageLinks = imageLinksFiltered

      // Here's where I want to trigger at each loop and change the state of what I have in the frontend
      setImageLinks(imageLinksFiltered);
```

I have an Image attached for a better understanding of what I'm doing.

[image]

Thank you for your help and explanation.

Comment: `useState` is a React hook, and can only be used inside a React component on the client-side. What exactly is the "backend" in this scenario? Is it an API route? Also, please make sure to post code as text directly (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)).

Comment: @juliomalves, yes it's an API route endpoint. The code is a small extract of the real code, I thought an Image just to show how I'm trying to change the state in the loop, would be more clear than all the lines. Since my question is juste how to proceed to change the state. I'm going to copy paste what's in the image, I guess it's better for the answers :)

Comment: There are two ways how the backend might "talk" to the frontend: Either in an HTTP response in reaction to an HTTP request made by the frontend (so the backend does not really "talk", rather it "answers"). Or via a websocket that the frontend has established to the backend (in this case, the frontend "listens" permanently and the backend can simply "talk").